# Problem not deleting AVD that there is multi mode

Tags: android, android-studio

I previously clicked run on multiple device and an AVD called motorola was created, but I can not delete it and it causes an error. The folder where the AVDs are stored is also empty.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to restart adb server in the Troubleshoot Device Connections.

Comment: I am very beginner and I am just learning. Please explain more or tell me more precise steps

Comment: Click Troubleshoot Device Connections button like your snaps. It will open Connection Assistant screen on your right side of Android Studio, click Next until you see the Restart  the ADB.